# Storing the numbers in textboxes to an array in C#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I have 18 textboxes and they are splitted 9 as numbers - 9 as percentages.
The numbers array is g[] the percentages array is w[].

So the thing I'm trying to do is, I want to store the numbers in 9 of the textboxes (textbox1,textbox2,.....textbox9) to an array g[], and the other 9 to array w[].
The inital values of array g[] and w[] are all zero.

```
 int[] g = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
 int[] w = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

each textbox number corresponds to an array index such as:

```
textbox2 - g[1]
textbox10 - w[0]
```

So if an input of only 10 in textbox1 and an input of 30 to textbox10 were to be put, it should look like this.

```
int[] g = new int[] { 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
int[] w = new int[] { 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

The important thing here is, there might not be a value input for textbox4 so the value should stay as 0.

What is the best way to do this with minumum amount of code and variable declarations?

Edit: This is what I tried so far but it doesn't seem like a good way to do this + I get an error

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' to type
>   'System.IConvertible'

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int[] g = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] w = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        List<TextBox> gList = new List<TextBox>();
        gList.Add(new TextBox { Text = textBox1.Text });
        gList.Add(new TextBox { Text = textBox2.Text });
        gList.Add(new TextBox { Text = textBox3.Text });
        gList.Add(new TextBox { Text = textBox4.Text });
        gList.Add(new TextBox { Text = textBox5.Text });
        gList.Add(new TextBox { Text = textBox6.Text });
        gList.Add(new TextBox { Text = textBox7.Text });
        gList.Add(new TextBox { Text = textBox8.Text });
        gList.Add(new TextBox { Text = textBox9.Text });

        List<TextBox> wList = new List<TextBox>();
        wList.Add(new TextBox { Text = textBox10.Text });
        wList.Add(new TextBox { Text = textBox11.Text });
        wList.Add(new TextBox { Text = textBox12.Text });
        wList.Add(new TextBox { Text = textBox13.Text });
        wList.Add(new TextBox { Text = textBox14.Text });
        wList.Add(new TextBox { Text = textBox15.Text });
        wList.Add(new TextBox { Text = textBox16.Text });
        wList.Add(new TextBox { Text = textBox17.Text });
        wList.Add(new TextBox { Text = textBox18.Text });

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
        {
            g[i] = Convert.ToInt32(gList[i]);

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            w[i] = Convert.ToInt32(wList[i]);

        }}
```

Comment: I think you need to give more information. Are you using WPF or WinForms? What are your textbox variable names? Can you post the code you've tried so far?

Comment: I'm using WinForms, the variable names are textbox1,textBox2, ..... textBox18. I couldn't find a good way to store textBox1.text to g[1] this is the issue.

Comment: Your sample code does not take elements of the form but instead creates new text boxes not shown in UI...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have form with 18 TextBoxes as you've described.

Step 1: get all textboxes into 2 lists for ease of access so there is array of `TextBox` with matching indexes for corresponding arrays.

```
var valueTextBoxes = form.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Take(9);    
var percentageTextBoxes = form.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Take(9);
```

Step 2: grab all values and convert them to array preserving default. `TryParse` gives ability to keep values of "not an integer" elements by returning current one for array. [Enumerable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) let to have value and index at the same time so we can grab old value of the array when `Text` does not represent integer value.

```
int value = 0; // for TryParse
g = valueTextBoxes
      .Select((t,index) => int.TryParse(t.Text, out value) ? value : g[index])
      .ToArray();

w = percentageTextBoxes
      .Select((t,index) => int.TryParse(t.Text, out value) ? value : w[index])
      .ToArray();
```

Step 3: update all text boxes if needed with regular `for` over corresponding arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you mean but, the easy way is to create an array of textboxes. 2 arrays of textboxes to manipulate them easier and then just put every value into the arrays. 
So using a for loop you would iterate through the arrays to copy them

```
for (int i = 0; i <= arrayMaxIndex; i++) {
    arrayNumbers[i] = arrayTxtBoxNum[i];
    // same for the other one
```

SORRY but I'm writing from my phone

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new textboxes to hold the values, so your cast is wrong

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
{
        //Wrong, it's a textbox!
        g[i] = Convert.ToInt32(gList[i]);
        //should be
        g[i] = Convert.ToInt32(gList[i].Text);
}
```

Also, instead of saving and casting after that, you can go directly with

```
g[0] = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
g[1] = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);

//And so on...
```